# matlab - change color of the arrows using quiver

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I would like to set the head color of quiver arrows to black, independently from the color of the arrow.

Here is not listed:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quivergroupproperties.html

and also not much luck on blogs up to now.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't think this can be done, the Arrow (the stick + arrowhead) in Matlab is one object and therefore only has 1 colour property; can you provide an example where it is different?

Comment: what about just superimpose a new plot with just the arrow heads?

Comment: I don't know, superimposing doesn't necessarily render well, for example, surf does not render in the imposed color properly. I don't know, if you can find an example to prove it's do-able...

Comment: If you really need this, you'll have to write your own custom plot function. It's possible that there are better options in the [Waterloo Graphics toolbox](http://waterloo.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the best options after a lot of digging:

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38278-draw-lines-with-arrows

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38331-draw-line-with-arrows-in-3d

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow-m

Hope that will useful to someone..!